# Detect the ethernet link up event and run the script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, network-interface

Hi i would like to run the script on ethernet link up event detection.

I tried to put the script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` but it didn't work for me. So Is there any way to detect the event every time and run the script ?

Comment: Add `post-up /etc/network/if-up.d/Your_script` to your `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration file if you are using a debian based distro.

Comment: Please tell us your distro

Comment: I am using ubuntu version 16.04 right now.

Comment: Hey thanx it worked when i manually down the interface by running the sudo ifdown eth0 command. And then bring up the interface by sudo ifup eth0 command. But i want to run this script when i detached the ethernet cable at run time and when i attached the ethernet cable it will detect the link up state and run the script . So can you guide me through this problem.

Comment: @user9298974 `ifplugd` might help you with what you need.